# Handling large data sets in R -- tutorials, best practices, etc

Tags: r, large-data

I am an R noob who is required to do various kinds of analysis on large data sets in R. So while looking around this site and elsewhere, it appeared to me that there are a lot of esoteric and less well known issues involved here - like which package to use when, what transformations to (not) apply on the data etc.

I am just wondering if there is a book/tutorial/guide that demystifies all this and presents the information in a systematic way? I prefer doing this instead of looking around, and collating information from different sources online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be a start: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: It might help to share some examples of what kind of analysis you want to do and what your data looks like.  Simple stats like means or complex regressions ? 200 variables accross a thousand rows, or 4 variables and 20 million rows ?

Comment: If you have really "large" datasets, you should perhaps have a look at relational databases. A starting point for this can be the "R Data Import/Export" manual that ships with R. N.B. the manual is also available via the "Manuals" section of the R website.

Comment: First, important question: What do *you* mean by large, and what do you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of blog posts I did on this subject of Large Data Sets with R.  There are a couple of packages like ff and bigmemory that make use of file swapping and memory allocation.  A couple of other packages make use of connectivity to databases such as sqldf, RMySQL, and RSQLite.

[R References for Handling Big Data](http://industrialengineertools.blogspot.com/2010/10/r-references-for-handling-big-data.html)

[Big Data Logistic Regression in R with ODBC](http://industrialengineertools.blogspot.com/2010/12/big-data-logistic-regression-with-r-and.html)